# Successful SQL login failing when publishing database through Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to publish my database through Visual Studio to a SQL Server running on a colleague's virtual machine (testing environment).

When testing the connection in Visual Studio, the test succeeds

[image: as you can see here]

When actually publishing the project to the server and database seen in the picture, publishing fails and I get this error message:

> *(47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 Fehler bei der Anmeldung für den Benutzer "sa".*"
>   Which translates to: "*Login error for the user "sa"*"

I'm not sure what to do here, as I can use the exact same credentials when logging into the SQL Server through SSMS without any problems. I am using Visual Studio Professional 2019 v16.6.2 if it helps.

Comment: Check with the password supplied

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI it's the same password i use to connect in SSMS. It's wokring perfectly fine there. Not sure which supplied password you mean (pretty new to this whole stuff).

Comment: I mean to say did you include user name and password in connection string?

Comment: Check this by IP address or system name for `server name`. its a visual studio problem. just use one off this method. some times you can use IP address, some times System name. try it.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake, i guess. In one of the scripts which are executed when publishing, i need to get data from another server where the login credentials for the "sa"-user are different. That's why i get the error message.